# How to subscribe to a new websocket session when switching chats in react

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I am working on a live chat feature where users can join many different chatrooms. I'm having difficulty subscribing to the new chatroom once switching rooms. It is sending the messages to the correct session, but not receiving them since it's not re-subscripting to the new session.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      client.configure({
        brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws',
        connectHeaders: sh,
        onConnect: () => {
          console.log('onConnect');
          setIsConnected(true);
          client.subscribe(`/secure/room/${convoId}`, mes => {
            const json = JSON.parse(mes.body);
            setMessages(prev => prev.concat(json));
          });
        },
        onDisconnect: () => {
          console.log('disconnected');
          setIsConnected(false);
        },
        onWebSocketClose: () => {
          client.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
      client.activate();
  }, [messages, convoId]);
```

Once a user switches to a new chatroom, to re-subscribe to the session

Answer (score 1):

Try to close the connection first before reconfigure it. 
like `client.disconnect();`

Comment: Thanks! that worked, I set up a listener to check when the location has changed and am forcing a disconnect.